# Lighthouse/Service Worker, how to return http 200 when offline

Tags: angularjs, webpack, offline, service-worker, lighthouse

My application currently uses webpack,angular js, and a service worker.

Using sw-precache plugin to create my service worker.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sw-precache-webpack-plugin

The service worker caching is going well and I can see my static resources being fetched from serviceworker.js from chrome dev tools.

Now when I run the lighthouse report I am getting the following error still :

```
URL responds with a 200 when offline
```

[image]

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse

In Dev tools when I switch on offline, I can actually see my page load. Some errors in console for some 3rd party scripts failing. Is this the reason for not getting url response 200 because I have some console errors from 3rd party i.e. sample error :

```
GET https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400,700 net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

What exactly is this audit looking for, and how can I achieve it ?

Edit : I added a picture of my network tab when I turn on offline, as I said the page loads fine. I notice my sw.js get's loaded from disk cache which I don't notice on other sites so could be something there.

[image]

Also here is sw.js content

```
'use strict';

var precacheConfig = [["/css/app.styles.77e2a0c3e7ac001193566741984a07f0.css","77e2a0c3e7ac001193566741984a07f0"],["/css/vendor.styles.582e79ead0684a8fb648ce9e543ad810.css","582e79ead0684a8fb648ce9e543ad810"],["/favicon.ico","70ef569d9a12f6873e86ed57d575cf13"],["/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot","e79bfd88537def476913f3ed52f4f4b3"],["/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.svg","a1adea65594c502f9d9428f13ae210e1"],["/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf","a37b0c01c0baf1888ca812cc0508f6e2"],["/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff","012cf6a10129e2275d79d6adac7f3b02"],["/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2","570eb83859dc23dd0eec423a49e147fe"],["/icons/launcher-icon-2x.png","91896b953c39df7c40b4772100971220"],["/icons/launcher-icon-3x.png","0aee2add7f56559aeae9555e495c3881"],["/icons/launcher-icon-4x.png","b164109dd7640b14aaf076d55a0a637b"],["/images/aa_logo_only.png","b5b46a8c2ead9846df1f1d3035634310"],["/images/developer.png","e8df747b292fe6f5eb2403c7180c31da"],["/images/facebook.png","8ab42157d0974099a72e151c23073022"],["/images/home-bg.jpeg","0a0f7da8574b037463af2f1205801e56"],["/images/logo.png","e8712312e08ca427d79a9bf34aedd6fc"],["/images/map.png","af3443ef4ab2890cae371c7a3de437ed"],["/images/pattern.png","114d593511446b9a4c6e340f7fef5c84"],["/images/twitter.png","99da44949cd33e16d2d551d42559eaf2"],["/index.html","1e9b5c4b3abba7e13d8d28c98cfb3bb5"],["/js/app.d9ada27616bf469d794d.js","8e2fc74de7d5c122ab8f0aca7e31b075"],["/js/vendor.d9ada27616bf469d794d.js","3bbba4569b6f3b88881b0533260905fe"],["/manifest.json","4bea29155995b63a9f2855637c0fe74c"]];
var cacheName = 'sw-precache-v2-45-' + (self.registration ? self.registration.scope : '');


var ignoreUrlParametersMatching = [/^utm_/];



var addDirectoryIndex = function (originalUrl, index) {
    var url = new URL(originalUrl);
    if (url.pathname.slice(-1) === '/') {
      url.pathname += index;
    }
    return url.toString();
  };

var createCacheKey = function (originalUrl, paramName, paramValue,
                           dontCacheBustUrlsMatching) {
    // Create a new URL object to avoid modifying originalUrl.
    var url = new URL(originalUrl);

    // If dontCacheBustUrlsMatching is not set, or if we don't have a match,
    // then add in the extra cache-busting URL parameter.
    if (!dontCacheBustUrlsMatching ||
        !(url.toString().match(dontCacheBustUrlsMatching))) {
      url.search += (url.search ? '&' : '') +
        encodeURIComponent(paramName) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(paramValue);
    }

    return url.toString();
  };

var isPathWhitelisted = function (whitelist, absoluteUrlString) {
    // If the whitelist is empty, then consider all URLs to be whitelisted.
    if (whitelist.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    // Otherwise compare each path regex to the path of the URL passed in.
    var path = (new URL(absoluteUrlString)).pathname;
    return whitelist.some(function(whitelistedPathRegex) {
      return path.match(whitelistedPathRegex);
    });
  };

var stripIgnoredUrlParameters = function (originalUrl,
    ignoreUrlParametersMatching) {
    var url = new URL(originalUrl);

    url.search = url.search.slice(1) // Exclude initial '?'
      .split('&') // Split into an array of 'key=value' strings
      .map(function(kv) {
        return kv.split('='); // Split each 'key=value' string into a [key, value] array
      })
      .filter(function(kv) {
        return ignoreUrlParametersMatching.every(function(ignoredRegex) {
          return !ignoredRegex.test(kv[0]); // Return true iff the key doesn't match any of the regexes.
        });
      })
      .map(function(kv) {
        return kv.join('='); // Join each [key, value] array into a 'key=value' string
      })
      .join('&'); // Join the array of 'key=value' strings into a string with '&' in between each

    return url.toString();
  };


var hashParamName = '_sw-precache';
var urlsToCacheKeys = new Map(
  precacheConfig.map(function(item) {
    var relativeUrl = item[0];
    var hash = item[1];
    var absoluteUrl = new URL(relativeUrl, self.location);
    var cacheKey = createCacheKey(absoluteUrl, hashParamName, hash, false);
    return [absoluteUrl.toString(), cacheKey];
  })
);

function setOfCachedUrls(cache) {
  return cache.keys().then(function(requests) {
    return requests.map(function(request) {
      return request.url;
    });
  }).then(function(urls) {
    return new Set(urls);
  });
}

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return setOfCachedUrls(cache).then(function(cachedUrls) {
        return Promise.all(
          Array.from(urlsToCacheKeys.values()).map(function(cacheKey) {
            // If we don't have a key matching url in the cache already, add it.
            if (!cachedUrls.has(cacheKey)) {
              return cache.add(new Request(cacheKey, {credentials: 'same-origin'}));
            }
          })
        );
      });
    }).then(function() {

      // Force the SW to transition from installing -> active state
      return self.skipWaiting();

    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  var setOfExpectedUrls = new Set(urlsToCacheKeys.values());

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.keys().then(function(existingRequests) {
        return Promise.all(
          existingRequests.map(function(existingRequest) {
            if (!setOfExpectedUrls.has(existingRequest.url)) {
              return cache.delete(existingRequest);
            }
          })
        );
      });
    }).then(function() {

      return self.clients.claim();

    })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  if (event.request.method === 'GET') {
    // Should we call event.respondWith() inside this fetch event handler?
    // This needs to be determined synchronously, which will give other fetch
    // handlers a chance to handle the request if need be.
    var shouldRespond;

    // First, remove all the ignored parameter and see if we have that URL
    // in our cache. If so, great! shouldRespond will be true.
    var url = stripIgnoredUrlParameters(event.request.url, ignoreUrlParametersMatching);
    shouldRespond = urlsToCacheKeys.has(url);

    // If shouldRespond is false, check again, this time with 'index.html'
    // (or whatever the directoryIndex option is set to) at the end.
    var directoryIndex = 'index.html';
    if (!shouldRespond && directoryIndex) {
      url = addDirectoryIndex(url, directoryIndex);
      shouldRespond = urlsToCacheKeys.has(url);
    }

    // If shouldRespond is still false, check to see if this is a navigation
    // request, and if so, whether the URL matches navigateFallbackWhitelist.
    var navigateFallback = '';
    if (!shouldRespond &&
        navigateFallback &&
        (event.request.mode === 'navigate') &&
        isPathWhitelisted([], event.request.url)) {
      url = new URL(navigateFallback, self.location).toString();
      shouldRespond = urlsToCacheKeys.has(url);
    }

    // If shouldRespond was set to true at any point, then call
    // event.respondWith(), using the appropriate cache key.
    if (shouldRespond) {
      event.respondWith(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
          return cache.match(urlsToCacheKeys.get(url)).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
              return response;
            }
            throw Error('The cached response that was expected is missing.');
          });
        }).catch(function(e) {
          // Fall back to just fetch()ing the request if some unexpected error
          // prevented the cached response from being valid.
          console.warn('Couldn\'t serve response for "%s" from cache: %O', event.request.url, e);
          return fetch(event.request);
        })
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What version of Lighthouse are you running? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/425 has some background on the test that earlier versions of Lighthouse used to perform, which didn't do a good job of accurately detecting offline navigations. If you're using an up to date version of Lighthouse and your page actually does load without a network connection, then opening a bug against the Lighthouse project with the reproduction steps would be ideal.

Comment: It's not because of the 3rd party resources. What lighthouse is pointing is that couldn't find a proper response for your main request. Did you tried setting offline mode and update on reload ?

Answer (score 3):

Some data like

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400,700`

does not support offline mode download these file manually and add them with local path again.